# How can I pass the pointer of a static 2D array to a structure/class?

Tags: c++

I have a problem when I try to pass the pointer of an array (which contains parameters needed by some functions in my program) to a structure, which then should be passed to those functions. GSL for example wants me to pass parameters in this way.

A little example program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct myparams
{
    double  * a;
    double ** b;
};

int main()
{
    double c[10]   = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    double d[4][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}};

    double** e = new double*[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       e[i] = new double[3];
    }

    myparams params;

    // THIS WORKS:
    params.a = c;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << params.a[i] << endl;
    }

    // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    params.b = d;

    // THIS WORKS:
    params.b = e;

    delete[] e;
}
```

What is the problem with

```
 params.b = d
```

The Compiler complains with `"cannot convert 'double[4][3]' to 'double**' in assignment"` or something like that (translated from german).

Comment: `double[n][m]` cannot decay into `double **`, while `double[n]` can decay into `double *`. That's why the first assignment is valid, and the latter isn't.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13273979/560648 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9557855/560648 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/7139014/560648

Comment: Also, never say "this doesn't work" again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`double d[4][3];` is an array of arrays. `double b**;` is a pointer to pointer. These types are not the same (the common "arrays are just pointers" you might have read on the internet is **wrong**).

Elements of `d` are of type `double[3]`. Arrays, when passed around, decay to pointers to their first element (see section 4.2. of C++ standard). `d` will decay to `double(*)[3]` (a pointer to array of 3 doubles).

Long story short, `double(*)[3]` is not convertible to `double**` and this is what compiler is telling you.

If you need to keep `d` as it is, you need to declare b as `double (*b)[3]`;

For more in-depth explanation, refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c).

Comment: Thank you! This was almost the solution. It's not `double (*b)[4]`, but `double (*b)[3]`.

Comment: I like how you accepted the incorrect answer over the correct one. That makes sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you point out what's incorrect, I'll fix it. Thank you.

Comment: @jrok: GriffinPeterson (the OP!) already did. Read his comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Aye, typo.

Answer (score 7):

It's because a pointer to a pointer (or an array of pointers as it can be used as) is not the same as an array of arrays. The layout in memory is incompatible.

For example, lets say we have these two declarations:

```
char aa[2][2] = { { 'a', 'b' }, { 'c', 'd' } };
char **pp;

pp = new char*[2];
pp[0] = new char[2];
pp[1] = new char[2];
```

The array `aa` looks like this in memory:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| aa[0][0] | aa[0][1] | aa[1][0] | aa[1][1] |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The "array" `pp` meanwhile looks like this:

```
+------+------+
| a[0] | a[1] |
+------+------+
   |      |
   |      v
   |      +---------+---------+
   |      | a[0][0] | a[0][1] |
   |      +---------+---------+
   V
   +---------+---------+
   | a[0][0] | a[0][1] |
   +---------+---------+
```

The "array" `pp` contains pointers to another "array"

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! But which member do I need in my structure `myparams` to store the pointer to the array `d`?

Comment: Okay I think that's better than [my diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7139014/560648). Dammit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I think yours look more "professional" than my crude ASCII art :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I did it in `pbrush`!

Comment: @GriffinPeterson: It's unwieldy, though. You're much better off with a 1D array representation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Why unwieldy? In terms of speed? I already used a 1D array representation and arranged my indexing, but now I just wanted to know how to implement it in 2D.

Comment: @GriffinPeterson: The type is unwieldy. Ownership semantics are unwieldy. It's just a mess.

Comment: I wish I could understand this

Comment: @GriffinPeterson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @GriffinPeterson In C++, there's really no need to use raw arrays anymore. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or if a fixed size "array" is wanted [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is the way to go. Now you can even [initialize them like normal arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Initializer_lists).

Comment: Let `T b[3][5]; T *a = &b[0][0];` Why doesn't `*(a + j*5 + i)` resolve to `b[j][i]`? At least, that's what I'm getting from the diagrams but not actually trying it.