# Passing C99 static 3D array with variable length to a function

Tags: c++, static, c99

I'm struggling to pass a C99 static 3D array of variable length to a function. I know this has been asked here on SO before, but I tried every solution I found so far, none of them worked. I have a following code:

```
int N;

int foo( ? ){

  // do stuff 

}

int main(){

   cin >> N;
   int arr[N][N][N];

   foo(arr);

return 0;
}
```

The question is what to put instead of '?'. Among other things I tried creating a pointer to this 3D array and passing the pointer according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14896642/9817200) but that also would compile.

Comment: If you make your array size depend on anything that is calculated at runtime that will be undefined behavior in C++ (because you tagged this as C++). If this *isn't* C++, please don't tag it as such.

Comment: Why are you right-shifting `cin`? (which is an undeclared variable anyway)

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have variable-style arrays.  What you can do is cast the address of the array to a pointer, and pass the dimensions, or even cast to a pointer to an array of the same size but different shape, then dereference that pointer.

One C++ technique you can use to sugar this, if you are selecting between a finite number of possible shapes, is to declare a `template< size_t L, size_t M, size_t N> int foo( int arr[L][M][N])`.  Another would be a multidimensional array class that wraps your array and its dimensions.  You can then construct an object, which aliases rather than copies the array, that you can index as `arr(i, j, k)`.